# javascript style.textDecoration contains an unexpected rgb value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does style.textDecoration contain an rgb value?

```js
style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('gettextDecorationfrom'));
weight = style.textDecoration;
document.getElementById("results").innerText = style.textDecoration;
```

```css
.myclass {
text-decoration:initial; 
}
```

```html
<div id="gettextDecorationfrom" class="myclass">
Test
</div>
<hr>
Result: <div id="results"></div>
```

I was expecting "initial" to be the result from this but was not expecting an rgb value to show up.

If underline is set the rgb value is also still there but just with 'underline' added, I don't understand why rgb is there in the first place?

```js
style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('gettextDecorationfrom'));
weight = style.textDecoration;
document.getElementById("results").innerText = style.textDecoration;
```

```css
.myclass {
text-decoration:underline; 
}
```

```html
<div id="gettextDecorationfrom" class="myclass">
Test
</div>
<hr>
Result: <div id="results"></div>
```

I was expecting "underline" to be the result from this but was not expecting an rgb value as well to show up.

Can I remove the rgb value from text-decoration no matter what the value is?

Comment: Initial is a preset rgb color so CSS just replaces initial with whatever your browser said it to

Comment: text-decoration seems to be able to carry, text-decoration-line, text-decoration-style, text-decoration-color, and text-decoration-thickness so do i need to just target text-decoration-line?

Comment: `underline` is a value, unlike `initial` which is just a preset rgb value which is why you are seeing a RGB value

Comment: you want `style.textDecorationLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, text-decoration is a shorthand property. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

That means it contains multiple properties. Specifically, it contains `text-decoration-line`, `text-decoration-color`, `text-decoration-style`, and `text-decoration-thickness`. That's why you see the RGB value, because it includes color in the `text-decoration` property.

If you just want the text-decoration-line property, then you can use `textDecorationLine`, but that still will never give you `initial` as you mentioned in your first example.

That's because `getComputedStyle` does not return what is in the CSS; it returns the style that actually ends up getting applied the element. That's why it's called **computed** style. `initial` is not a computed style, it's a value that instructs the browser to compute the style by using whatever the initial style was, which for text-decoration-line is none, as you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line#formal_definition

If you want to get that `initial`, you will have to actually inspect the stylesheet itself. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Answer (score 1):

`text-decoration` has a default color, usually your browser's (black)

You can trim of the rgb part of the string with `.replace` and a bit of regex.

This will cut out the rgb part regardless of the rgb(x.x.x) values, as you wanted.

BUT! You wont be able to get `initial` as a result, because `initial` replaces to the default `none` value at `text-decoration`

```js
style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('gettextDecorationfrom'));
weight = style.textDecoration;
text = weight.replace(/ ?rgb\(([^;]*)\)/gm, '');
document.getElementById("results").innerText = text;
```

```css
.myclass {
  text-decoration:underline; 
}
```

```html
<div id="gettextDecorationfrom" class="myclass">
  Test
</div>
<hr>
Result: <div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of both answers I was able to get what i needed.
The answer by Instance Hunter had the JavaScript `textDecorationLine` i was missing which allowed me to use FHJTDSDG's answer without the regex.

Working example..

```js
updateresult()

function toggleunderline() {
if (weight === "none") {
document.getElementById("gettextDecorationfrom").style.textDecorationLine = "underline"
updateresult()
} else {
document.getElementById("gettextDecorationfrom").style.textDecorationLine = "initial"
updateresult()
}
}

function updateresult(){
style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('gettextDecorationfrom'));
weight = style.textDecorationLine;
document.getElementById("results").innerText = weight;
}
```

```css
.myclass {
text-decoration:initial; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleunderline()">
Toggle underline
</button>
<div id="gettextDecorationfrom" class="myclass">
Test
</div>
<hr>
Result: <div id="results"></div>
```